# Can't get Advanced Access to public_profile on a disabled Facebook Login app because of invalid privacy policy link in external app store

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-play, facebook-login, privacy-policy

Facebook disabled our app saying that our app *hangs or crashes during Facebook Login*.

I looked at [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com) and noticed that we don't have `Advanced Access` to `public_profile` which seems to be required now:

[image]

`public_profile` `Advanced Access` should be **auto-granted**, especially given that our app has been reviewed and active for a long time now:

[image]

However, after I request `Advanced Access` and provide my password, the page refreshes (first hangs and freezes for several seconds) but I still only have Standard Access.

So far, our story is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543684/cant-get-advanced-access-to-public-profile-on-a-disabled-app) (also seems unresolved). As suggested in the answer to that question, I did describe the problem in Facebook Appeal forms several times but it has been **ignored** and we got **the same semi-automated answer** every time.

However, what makes our case *slightly different* from the question linked above is that after I unsuccessfully request `Advanced Access` and re-enter my password, the following message shows up:

[image]

[app store](https://play.google.com/) in the above links to our app's page on Google Play. I double-checked that our **privacy policy link is there, is live and doesn't return any errors**. I also tested it with [Facebook's Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and says that the link is fine.

I'm sure lots of developers must be facing similar issues, has anyone come across a solution that works? Or perhaps the right support contact at Facebook to reach out to? Thanks!

Comment: how did you solve it? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: If I remember correctly what solved the problem for now in the end was nothing specific - I just kept on submitting Appeals so that it eventually worked. Answer to this question helped me find the write wording for the Appeal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543684/cant-get-advanced-access-to-public-profile-on-a-disabled-app

Comment: Same problem here, did anyone solve this? Im soooooooo fu******ng tired of Facebook support/appeal team with responding the same over and over again. My app has been disabled for a month now and I cant figure out what is wrong.